# Make a prediction using Octave plsregress

Tags: regression, pca

I have a good (or at least a self-consistent) calibration set and have applied PCA and recently PLS regression on n.i.r. spectrum of known mixtures of water and additive to predict the percentage of additive by volume. I thus far have done self-calibration and **now want to predict the concentration from the n.i.r.spectrum blindly.**  Octave returns `XLOADINGS`, `YLOADINGS`, `XSCORES`, `YSCORES`, `COEFFICIENTS`, and `FITTED` with the `plsregress` command.  The "fitted" is the estimate of concentration.  Octave uses the `SIMPLS` approach.

How do I use these returned variables to predict concentration give a new samples spectrum?

Scores are usually denoted by T and loadings by P and X=TP'+E where E is the residual.  I am stuck.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that T and P are X scores and loadings, respectively. Unlike PCA, PLS has scores and loadings for Y as well (usually denoted U and Q).

---

While the [documentation of `plsregress`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/statistics/function/plsregress.html) is sketchy at best, the paper it refers to [Sijmen de Jong: SIMPLS: an alternativ approach to partial least squares regression Chemom Intell Lab Syst, 1993, 18, 251-263, DOI: 10.1016/0169-7439(93)85002-X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0169-7439(93)85002-X)
discusses prediction with equations (36) and (37), which give:

**Yhat0** = **X0** **B**

Note that this uses centered data **X0** to predict centered y-values. **B** are the `COEFFICIENTS`.

---

I recommend that as a first step you predict your training spectra and make sure you get the correct results (`FITTED`).